# Can I customize ui elements from another customization project that are an extension to a base page?

Tags: acumatica

I have a project which customizes a base page that is to remain unchanged, but I have a custom UI element within that project that I must alter. When I create another project and include the base page in the Customized Screens list, I do not see the customized elements from the first project. Is it possible to get these elements into the secondary project from the first project and customize them, or do I need to make all altercations to the original customizations from the first project within the first project?

Comment: You need to do changes to the custom UI elements in the project which adds that elements. Any customization sees only original page structure + changes in it and ignoring any changes done by other packages.

Comment: That's what I figured. I just wanted to get a confirmation on that.